# Expressions in RDLC reports

Tags: c#, reporting, rdlc

Is it possible to add/change expressions in rdlc reports from C# code and how would I do it? I'm using VS 2010.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a parameter set to an object and than fill the object with the information you want and send it as parameter.

Comment: How is that done? Specifically, I want to be able to populate Switch() expression - that means I need pairs of parameters. Would this work: `Switch(Fields!MyField.Value = Parameters!MyParameter1, Parameters!MyParameter1)`. How would the code look? 
Thanks